# Curator working late discovers the night watchman is the vandal and the Egyptian gods are real

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mythology

I’d love to identify a short story I read in an anthology that must’ve been printed in the 80s or 90s.

The main character is a museum curator and she’s working late studying a statue of an Egyptian god. She learns that the recent attacks of vandalism were perpetrated by the night watchman who wants to destroy “heathen” artefacts. There’s a confrontation and she’s saved somehow by the god.

Comment: Is the curator attacked and tied up or immobilised in some way by the night watchman? I have a vague memory of a story along these lines.

Comment: @JohnRennie I don't remember, but there's definitely a confrontation between them and she calls on the god who's statue she's studying.

Comment: This sounds like a combination between _The Red Pyramid_ and _Aru Shah and the End of Time_... But those are both standalone books, so that can't be right!

Answer (score -2):

This sounds a little like [The Night at the Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_at_the_Museum#Original_storyline).

The 2006 film is based on a 1993 children’s picture book and according to Wikipedia a junior novelisation also exists.

> On his first night at the job, he wakes up to find all of the dinosaur skeletons have vanished. He finds nothing looking around the museum, Central Park, and at the planetarium next door. Eventually Hector discovers that the dinosaurs come alive every night, and rather than keep the museum safe from the world outside, his job is to keep the world outside safe from the dinosaurs inside.

In the film version IIRC, the current guard is planning to rob the museum and leave the new guard to take the fall.

Comment: Whilst somewhat similar I don't think this matches that well. IIRC the night watchman doesn't vandalise at all, either the new or the old one(s). And it's not Egyption gods but actual Egyptian mummys.

Comment: Not to mention that the protagonist (and viewpoint character) is the night watchman,  not a curator.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot honestly I didn't think it was a super match myself. But it shares the general gist and I've seen worse matches actually be right before. And if not, hopefully it will inspire someone else by association.

Comment: Aye it's always worth a try, it just doesn't seem that close to me but we shall see!

Comment: There was a story in a short anthology by Brian Jacques of Redwall fame in which a teen broke into a museum to graffiti a sarcophagus or some such; turned out that the caretaker was a secret priest of Anubis and I believe he was mummified in the end. Sounds similar to the OP's question but not quite right either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There are a few similarities but the story I'm trying to find is pretty much just the single short episode and just the three characters -- the curator, the watchman, and the god.